# Python ImportError

Tags: python, qr-code

I have installed pyqrcode => [PyQRCode](http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/) on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64.
by running make && sudo make install.

At then end of the successful make/make install, the last line is:

> Installed
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qrcode-0.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

But when I try to import qrcode I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "qrcode/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from qrcode import _qrcode
ImportError: cannot import name _qrcode
```

Comment: I also tried using pip and it said qrcode was already installed (tried after installing from source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo pip install qrcode` worked just fine for me.

My guess is that after compiling, you started Python up from the source directory, and so it looked in the local `qrcode` directory -- i.e. `pyqrcode-0.2.1/qrcode` instead of in the usual Python path.  Try running it from another directory.  To be specific:

```
~/sys/pyqrcode-0.2.1$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import qrcode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "qrcode/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from qrcode import _qrcode
ImportError: cannot import name _qrcode
>>> 
~/sys/pyqrcode-0.2.1$ cd ~
~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import qrcode
>>> qrcode
<module 'qrcode' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qrcode/__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: hmm. Almost solves my problem! If i run python from the root, I get a bit further. It complains: _qrcode._setExceptionTypes(JavaError, InvalidArgsError)    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_setExceptionTypes

Comment: Something seems strange about the source version.  Try deleting the one you installed and try the pip one again, which appears to work for me, anyway (same 12.04 x86_64 setup as you're using.)  [IOW, I think this is an independent problem from the ImportError.  That was a path search order issue; this new one is a more fundamental problem.]